# How do I get multiple optional values of JSON data?

Tags: java, json, exception, jackson

There is a JSON data that contains several optional fields:

My code to get these values is:

```
String name = null;
String family_name = null;
String given_name = null;
String suffix_name = null;
try {
    JSONObject contact = new JSONObject("{\"givenName\":[\"John\"],\"familyName\":[\"Doe\"]}");

    name = contact.getJSONArray("name").getString(0);
    family_name = contact.getJSONArray("familyName").getString(0);
    given_name = contact.getJSONArray("givenName").getString(0);
    suffix_name = contact.getJSONArray("honorificPrefix").getString(0);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("ContactsManager", "Failed to parse json data: "+e);
}
```

The problem here is, if "name" is null(as the example above), all other fields will failed to be retrieved, which is not I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not add a check before reading

```
if (contact.has("name")) {
  name = contact.getJSONArray("name").getString(0);
}
```

Comment: after `contact.has("name")` you can add one more condition of instanceof operator `contact.get("name") instanceof JSONArray` before using getJSONArray("name") to avoid any Class mismatch exception